# Ansible installation on Windows 10 giving following error

Tags: ansible

Please someone suggest me how to install Ansible on Windows 10 and I've tried to do the same from GIT Bash that didn't help.

```
Error Log:

copying lib\ansible\galaxy\data\network\tests\inventory -> build\lib\ansible\galaxy\data\network\tests
    copying lib\ansible\config\base.yml -> build\lib\ansible\config
    copying lib\ansible\config\module_defaults.yml -> build\lib\ansible\config
    error: symbolic link privilege not held

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\info2m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\pip-install-vr60imm0\\ansible\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-record-wh599uda\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-install-vr60imm0\ansible\
```

Comment: Hi, Please suggest me this change will do "'C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\pip-install-vr60imm0\\ansible\\setup.py" from the error log mentioned in the initial log.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible is not supported on Windows

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31419#issuecomment-334787881

"We do not support installing ansible directly on a windows machine. You will need a linux like operating system to install ansible on. This is covered in [http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_installation.html#control-machine-requirements"](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_installation.html#control-machine-requirements%22)